# NuGet - uninstall & remove dependencies ONLY if other projects don't depend on them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a NuGet package with nothing in it except dependencies on other packages. So basically think of it as "package of packages." One of those packages has a dependency on a third-party software that is also used by other parts of our project.

My problem is that I want to uninstall the package-of-packages, and to do that I specify the `-RemoveDependencies` option. However, I get an error saying "Unable to uninstall `<third-party package>` because `<another package we use>` depends on it.

Is there a way to uninstall dependencies only if other projects don't depend on it?

Comment: Am afraid not. You will have to live with it or remove all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my desired result by changing the "package-of-packages" paradigm. Instead of tagging other packages as dependencies, I created a `tools/` folder and inside put an install.ps1 and uninstall.ps1 powershell script which run at install or uninstall-time. [Read more here.](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal)

In those scripts I simply issue the command to install or uninstall the packages of my choice. By default, `Uninstall-Package` doesn't remove dependencies, which makes my job much easier. It doesn't achieve my initial goal of only removing dependencies that aren't needed in other parts of the project, it just leaves any second-order dependencies intact. This isn't a problem for me because only one of my packages has a second-order dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For a single project

```
Get-Packages -ProjectName <project> | Uninstall-Package -ProjectName <project>
```

in the Package Management Console should do the trick.

Packages that cannot be uninstalled because of dependencies will fail to uninstall, while those that have no dependencies will be uninstalled successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You need to uninstall all NuGet packages that dependent on it first. Then you can remove these dependencies.

Because if there has other packages dependent on it, if you remove it, the packages will lose the dependencies which will lead this packages could not work anymore.

Comment: The is the opposite problem to what the OP wants.